# DescreteObjectKeyFrame value binding is not refreshing for WPF Storyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-animation

My aim is to show time in a `Label` and update it in every second. I am using `Storyboard` and `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`. The `Storyboard` implementation is working but the `DescreteObjectKeyFrame` value that is bind to `DateTime.Now` is not getting refreshed. Can anybody please help to fix the issue. This approach is chosen to replace the existing implementation using `Timer`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mscorlib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Label FontSize="40"
               ContentStringFormat="hh:mm:ss">
            <Label.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content"
                                                           Duration="0:0:3"
                                                           RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="."
                                                            KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{Binding Source={x:Static mscorlib:DateTime.Now}}"
                                                            KeyTime="0:0:2" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What happens when you instead of DateTime.Now bind to a property with change notification? I suspect it would still not update, but might be worth a try. But when you have such a property, you would of course not need the Storyboard at all.

Comment: @Clemens Chosen storyboard to remove a viewmodel property and timer instance

Comment: Sure, but as you see that doesn't work.

Comment: How is the value supposed to be getting refreshed if you don't raise an event to notify the view to refresh it? Your solution simply doesn't work.

Comment: @mm8 The above snippet doesn't have any DataBinding to explicitly invoke the property changed. The Storyboard is not picking the latest updated value even if I follow viewmodel property binding approach

Comment: So what exactly is your question?